# How to display image from database to listview?

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to android development. I am able to restore string from my sqite Database to my listview. Now I want to add image to my listview via the image's path that I saved to my Database(I was able to save the path already, my only problem is how do I add that path in my code below). Here's my code:

```
private void populateFields()  {
    // if the row is not null from the database. 
    if (mRowId != null) {
        cursor = studentsDbAdapter.queueStud(mRowId);
        String[] from = new String[]{StudentsDbAdapter.KEY_StudentName,StudentsDbAdapter.KEY_StudentID,StudentsDbAdapter.KEY_Course,StudentsDbAdapter.KEY_Year,StudentsDbAdapter.KEY_Contact,StudentsDbAdapter.KEY_Email};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textstud,R.id.textstudID};
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.stud_row, cursor, from, to);
        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);                 
    }                   
}
```

I don't know if this is gonna help but in my other activity where I saved the image's path I was able to restore the image by using the following code:

```
public void showpic() {

    //LoginDataBaseAdapter db = studentsDbAdapter.open();
    boolean emptytab = false;
    boolean empty = studentsDbAdapter.checkPic(null, emptytab);

    //Cursor cursor = loginDataBaseAdapter.fetchProfileImageFromDatabase();  

    if(empty==false) {  

        String pathName = studentsDbAdapter.getImapath(studID);
        File image = new  File(pathName); 
        if (image.exists()) {
            ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.studpic);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how you are storing image in database .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make custom adapter.

```
In adapter you can display image like this,

public static void ShowPicture(String fileName, ImageView pic) { 
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName); 
    FileInputStream is = null; 
    try { 
        is = new FileInputStream(f); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("error: ",String.format( "ShowPicture.java file[%s]Not Found",fileName)); 
        return; 
    } 

    Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, null); 
    pic.setImageBitmap(bm); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing your image in DB ?

If Stored as blob, use BitmapFactory to convert it to Bitmap and set it to ImageView.

Or if it is stored as Base64 encoded string, then decode it and convert it to Bitmap.

Comment: I stored the image's path to my database. I saved it from a different activity.